# Force on a magnetic dipole

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, dipole

How to deduce the force on a magnetic dipole given by $F = \nabla(m \cdot B)$ from the Lorentz force?

Comment: Treat the magnetic dipole as an infinitesimal square current loop and compute the Lorentz force on it. [Details](http://teacher.pas.rochester.edu/PHY217/LectureNotes/Chapter6/LectureNotesChapter6.html#Heading11)

Comment: A more formal approach, if you like Dirac delta functions, starts with the [current density for a point magnetic dipole](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/536989/current-density-mathbfj-of-particle-with-magnetic-dipole-moment-mathbfm/537042#537042), $\mathbf{J}=\boldsymbol{\nabla}\times\mathbf{m}\delta\left(\mathbf{r}\right)$, and computes the Lorentz force on that, as a volume integral. To understand this expression for the current density, see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetization#Magnetization_current).